# How to get all posts from same day but posted in previous years?

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm trying to get SELECT FROM all posts that were posted on this day, but previous years.
Basically like a history on this day thing.

Here is the code I'm trying to build on:

```
  public function get_on_this_day_events($lang_id, $limit)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM (" . $this->query_string() . " AND posts.lang_id = ? WHERE posts.created_at >= CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC LIMIT ?) AS table_posts";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array(clean_number($lang_id), clean_number($limit)));
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for same day in the previous year you can use this condition
`created_at = DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`

you code after edits :

```
public function get_on_this_day_events($lang_id, $limit)
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts  WHERE  posts.lang_id = ? AND  posts.created_at = DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)  ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC LIMIT ? ";

            $query = $this->db->query($sql, array(clean_number($lang_id), clean_number($limit)));

            return $query->result();
        }
```

**If you want to retrieve all the previous years**

you can try change the codition to
`day(NOW()) = day(created_at) and Month(NOW()) = Month(created_at) and year(NOW()) != year(created_at)`

which means the same `day` and `month` but not the `year`

you code after edits :

```
public function get_on_this_day_events($lang_id, $limit)
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts  

             WHERE  posts.lang_id = ? AND 
             day(NOW()) = day(posts.created_at) 
             and Month(NOW()) = Month(posts.created_at) 
             and year(NOW()) != year(posts.created_at)

             ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC LIMIT ?";

                $query = $this->db->query($sql, array(clean_number($lang_id), clean_number($limit)));

                return $query->result();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand that "INTERVAL 1 YEAR" only gets the posts from this day, *a* year ago, I'm looking for a "this day, *years ago* ". like years except the current year

Comment: Oh Okay,I update it added another query for retrieve all previous years and not this year , kindly check

Comment: This looks more like what I'm looking for. Now I'm getting a database error: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE day(NOW()) = day(posts.created_at) and Month(NOW()) = Month(posts.c...' at line 7

Comment: its my bad , updated kindly check

Comment: Weird I still get the database Error Number: 1064, I googled it and it looks like the reasons are one or more of these: Correct mistyped commands, obsolete commands, reserved words, missing data. I'm sure missing data is not one of them, that I've checked.

Comment: @Damon Okay, updated

Answer (score 0):

This was solved, here is the code

```html
public function get_on_this_day_events($lang_id, $limit)
    {
        $sql = "select * from posts where 
                                    (extract(day from posts.created_at) = extract(day from current_timestamp()) 
                                    and extract(month from posts.created_at) = extract(month from current_timestamp())
                                    and extract(year from posts.created_at) < extract(year from current_timestamp())) 
                                    ";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array(clean_number($lang_id), clean_number($limit)));
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).